# Trouble with firebase and facebook login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

My problem is where sign with `Facebook` I got an error with Firebase authentication,the method `signInWithCredential(AuthCredencial credencial)` in `OncompleteListener` the result of task is not successful and I can't understand why.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            System.out.println("Entro");
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }
    ...
    });

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            }
        }
    };
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {

    AuthCredential credential = facebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d("TAG","TERMINOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al iniciar en firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

---

if you run the Listener never change the state and never go to my `MainActivity`, this code it's made from Firebase tutorial and Facebook tutorial. Facebook sign in good but Firebase no, sorry for my English and thanks!

Comment: did you enable your facebook authentication on firebase service end?

Comment: yes i have enable the authentication on firebase, and the uri for facebook to 
![Valid XHTML](http://i.imgur.com/15DywA6.png
)
![Valid XHTML](http://i.imgur.com/b8gaWpK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem after look in webs and other people, forums, etc. discover what my app id in firebase and facebook developers are not the same